# How am i supposed to pass the value of a slider to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, google-chrome-extension, html5-audio

So i'm trying to pass a value of a slider onto a javascript function, to set the volume of an audio. I'm very new to javascript so i'm not quite sure what i'm doing but Chrome complains about `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`.

HTML5 code

```
<div class="mt-2">Volume</div>
        <div class="slidecontainer">
         <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="musicVolume">
         <output id="musicVolume"> </output>
```

Javascript code

```
// Create audio object
var themeAudio = new Audio()
volumeSlider = parseInt(document.getElementById("musicVolume").value );  
themeAudio.volume = volumeSlider
themeAudio.loop = true
```

(The javascript code is under it's own file, background.js while the HTML code is under popup.html)

Comment: It can happen if the script runs before the element's declaration/creation, in which case you can simply move your `<script>` tag to the end of html. Another possibility is that you load the script in the wrong place so you should show us how you do it (in the question).

Answer (score 0):

You can put `<script />` in the bottom on your `<body>` or add attribute `deffer` for script